# Unable to fetch data from website

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new to java.

Am trying to fetch the data from webpage while clicking a button from .jsp page. I used Window.open() to open a webpage, but unable to get the control values from that webpage.

I just tried with Window.open(). No need to open that webpage. Only thing is, we need to read the data from that webpage either by open the page or without open that page.
Please help on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting textbox values using JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134369/getting-textbox-values-using-jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really clear with the question. But will attempt to re-phrase it-

```
 What you are trying to do is open any web page from your JSP (using some Window.open()) & then access any element from the web page into your JSP.
```

I personally dont think if this can be done because then it would be serious security threat to access confidential data [like passwords, etc] from any page.

Comment: hi munna, thanks. That webpage is already athenticated and we are legally accessing the values. In better way I will explain little more. I have one tool. It is dealing with requests and resolutions. And after closing that request, we have to made a report on daily basis.So am trying to do this automation. From that request we need to get requester name, request opened date etc.. through our java program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to say. But I guess you want to pass the value from the child window to the parent window. For that you need to use the code below.

```
opener.document.form.parent_field.value =  document.form.child_field.value;
```

This code will go in your child window. What it does is set the value in parent's field named "parent_filed" with the value in child's filed names "child_field"

Comment: thanks for your quick reponse. Actually  my query is like one web page(ex:google account userprofile) have fields like username, date etc.. using my java code, I have to read that username,date values into our jsp page.